# How to use SQL LIKE to match result

Tags: mysql

[Been looking at how I could query the database](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1276352&seqNum=7) to get results using `LIKE`.

For example I have a table with two columns `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo: 202
bar: "what-my-life-is-like"
```

When I query:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE foo = 202 AND bar LIKE '%what-is-my-life-is-like%'
```

I expect to get a result, instead I get nothing. How to get the result?

It seems not to like that the "is" comes after the "what-"

Complete example:

```
// php
$name_path = "what-is-my-life-is-like";

query:
"SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE foo = 202 AND bar LIKE '%" . $name_path . "%'";
```

Comment: "I expect to get a result" _Why?_ You cannot say 'where the string contains `is-` before `my`', give a record that does not meet that criterion, and get a match. If you want the `is-` to be optional, then replace it with `%` too. At a glance, it looks like the tutorial just doesn't provide any examples like this, i.e. where the `%` occurs between other text, which simply makes it incomplete IMO.

Comment: The string would be a variable so I cannot know what value it is.

Comment: What string? Where does the variable come from? Provide a complete example. What you are really trying to do seems very vague.

Comment: Hi @underscore_d, Ive made the change.

Comment: It is still totally unclear why you expect to get a result, i.e. why you expect `%what-is-my-life-is-like%` to match `what-my-life-is-like`, nor why there is any difference at all (e.g. whether you want some kind of fuzzy matching), nor what degree of differences should be allowed and where (i.e. what the rules are for the fuzzy matching). But in this single case, you could simply try `%what-%my-life-is-like%`, for example.

Comment: Yes....typo...sorry. refresh to see

Answer (score 0):

First of all you searching a string that dose not exists. as you explained in the table your string is

> what-my-life-is-like

and you querying as string

> what-is-my-life-is-like

with a "is" in the middle of "what" and "my". if you have both of string in your table you can skip it as follows.

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE foo = 202 AND bar LIKE "%what%-life-is-like%"

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE>
WHERE foo=202 AND bar LIKE '%what%-my-life-is-like%'
```